# Firefox unable to parse XSLT, IE9 just ignores it, help debugging?

Tags: xml, xslt

could someone help me debugging this XSLT? I can't afford to spend too much time with this as I have a lot of things to do this week, I've been trying for at least half an hour but still can't find what is wrong with it. My skills with XSLT are limited, and we are asked way too much for what we do in class, plus, Firefox didn't help too much, aside of complaining about acuted characters (á, é...).

Here's a pastie link, mainly because the code was too big: http://pastie.org/6452944

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decent XML editor would probably tell you what the problems are:

- You have an opening `<table>` tag where you should have a closing `</table>` tag.
- `&eq;` is meaningless in standard XML; you should use `=`
- `<xsl:choose>` does not allow a `select` attribute
- It is illegal to end an XPath with a slash.

And a logic error:

- `@observaciones = urgente` tests whether `@observaciones` is equal to the *node* `urgente` (which does not exist in this case). You would need to use `@observaciones = 'urgente'`.

When these are fixed, I imagine it will work.  Here is a fixed-up version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/empresa">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="sede/nombre" />
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="empresa.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr class="titulo">
            <td>
              <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="sede/nombre" />
              </p>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
              <img alt="empresa" src="empresa.png" />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="subtitulo">
            <td>
              <p>Albaran</p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="pedido">
            <xsl:sort select="@id" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pedido">
    <tr class="cuerpo">
      <td rowspan="3">
        <span>
          <xsl:value-of select="sucursal/nombre" />
        </span>
        <br />
        <span>
          <xsl:value-of select="sucursal/region" />
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="fecha">
      <td>
        <p>
          Albaran con fecha de: <xsl:value-of select="fecha" />
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="npedido">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" />
    </tr>
    <tr class="articulos">
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span>Cod. de articulo</span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <span>N. de unidades</span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <span>Precio por unidad</span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <span>Observaciones</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="articulo">
            <xsl:sort select="@id" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="observaciones">
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@observaciones[. = 'urgente' or
                                                    . = 'incompleto']" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="articulo">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@cant" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@precioud" />
      <xsl:call-template name="Cell">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@observaciones" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="articulo/@* | pedido/@id"
                name="Cell">
    <xsl:param name="value" select="." />
    <td>
      <span>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
      </span>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@observaciones">
    <strong>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(., 1, 1), 'it', 'IT'),
                                     substring(., 2))"/>
    </strong>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I was using Notepad++ as my editor and worked this in a rush because of a SQL exam the new day (that is, today, which was easier than I expected). Anyways, thank you for pointing the errors rather than just correcting my file, somethings were careless of mine, but most were things I didn't understand correctly.